# migrations (structure updates) for dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Just start to work with AWS lambda and DynamoDB, and can't understand is it possible to setup some kind of migration tool like liquibase or flyway. My goal is upload lambda function to cloud, and be sure that my dynamodb instance contain latest changes, or will create all required tables.

For now I can find only ways how to create table in dynamodb, and I suppose that create and update is similar operations. But I can't understand how to run this code with lambda update. Also, I will have many lambda functions, and most probably all of them will use same tables. Is there way, how to configure it? How to manage state of dynamodb? Or I should just adjust dynamodb instance from aws UI?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you need strong schema and migrations, then DynamoDB might be not the best suited DB for the use case

Comment: I want to manage at least secondary indexes, and have possibility to run new environment easily.

Comment: Very good question. I am very surprised that there isn't a tool or concept yet. I see that with CDK, SAM, etc one can add tables or global secondary indexes afterwards. But I am also missing a solution for automated bulk updates of documents integrated in release pipeline. IMHO this even with nosql not an edge case in real world applications.

Comment: I have problems even with indexes. For an example, if I want to change index from numeric type to string type, I need to recreate tables. If I need to recreate tables, I need to drop dynamodb stack, otherwise I will have problems with future deploys. Dynamodb stack is dependency from lambda stack, so I need to drop lambda stack as well. May be I'm doing something wrong, but it is really pain.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB is not the best option for strong-schemed migration-ready DB usage. But, the whole infrastructure can be easily maintained using CloudFormation templates (or, what I suggest more, SAM/CDK).
What can You achieve using CF? I one single stack update You can add/remove DDB tables, change indexes, change permissions for resources, update lambda code, and many more. If anything fails it will be rollbacked to a previous, stable state. 
Please check this out:
[AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)
[AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html)